# Facing a problem with render function in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I used to have such code in my story for Dialog component

```
const meta: Meta<typeof Dialog> = {
  component: Dialog,
  title: "Feedback/Dialog/Dialog",
}

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Dialog>
```

Then I decide to change it to such structure

```
const meta = {
  component: Dialog,
  title: "Feedback/Dialog/Dialog",
} satisfies Meta<typeof Dialog>

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>
```

And now I am facing issues with my stories, because to see them I use render function

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react"
import { Box } from "@mui/material"
import { FC, useState } from "react"
import { Dialog, DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogContentText, DialogTitle } from "components/Dialog"
import { Button } from "components/Button"
import { Typography } from "components/Typography"

const meta = {
  component: Dialog,
  title: "Feedback/Dialog/Dialog",
} satisfies Meta<typeof Dialog>

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>

type DialogWrapperComponentProps = {
  title?: boolean
  actions?: boolean
}

const DialogWrapperComponent: FC<DialogWrapperComponentProps> = ({ title = false, actions = false }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen)
  }

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleChange}>
          Открыть модальное окно
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <Dialog open={isModalOpen} onClose={handleChange}>
        {title && <DialogTitle>Фильтр</DialogTitle>}
        <DialogContent sx={{ paddingTop: title ? "0" : "64px" }}>
          <DialogContentText>Lorem ipsum</DialogContentText>
          <Box style={{ width: "376px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }}>content</Box>
          <Box style={{ width: "376px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }}>content</Box>
        </DialogContent>
        {actions && (
          <DialogActions>
            <Button sx={{ width: "180px", borderWidth: "1px", borderStyle: "solid", borderColor: "neutral.800" }} disabled>
              <Typography variant="titleSmall">Сбросить</Typography>
            </Button>
            <Button sx={{ width: "180px" }} variant="contained">
              <Typography variant="titleSmall">Применить</Typography>
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        )}
      </Dialog>
    </Box>
  )
}

export const Default: Story = {
  render: () => <DialogWrapperComponent title actions />,
}

export const WithoutActions: Story = {
  render: () => <DialogWrapperComponent title />,
}

export const WithoutTitle: Story = {
  render: () => <DialogWrapperComponent actions />,
}

export const WithoutActionsAndTitle: Story = {
  render: () => <DialogWrapperComponent />,
}
```

The issue is that all four stories requiring now **args**

```
Property 'args' is missing in type '{ render: () => JSX.Element; }' but required in type '{ args: { "aria-describedby"?: string | undefined; "aria-labelledby"?: string | undefined; children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<DialogClasses> | undefined; ... 291 more ...; inlist?: any; }; }'.
```

What do i have to do to fix that problem?